# Using onkeyup to display output whilst typing

Tags: javascript, forms, onkeyup

I am trying to use "onkeyup" to display the realtime output of a form. It appears to be working just fine in my Codepen project, but not in VS Code. I can't pinpoint where I'm going wrong.

Here's my Codepen: https://codepen.io/jonah-cockshaw/pen/OJOrapb

Here's the code from VS Code:

```
<h3>Chiller capacity</h3>
<p>Please input each chiller’s rated capacity in kW. The rated capacity is on the chiller nameplate.</p>

<label for="chiller-1">Chiller 1</label><br>
<input type="number" onkeyup=`addAll()` class="input-field" id="chiller-1" name="chiller-1" placeholder="Input number in KW" value="" required><br>

<label for="chiller-2">Chiller 2</label><br>
<input type="number" onkeyup=`addAll()` class="input-field" id="chiller-2" name="chiller-2"placeholder="Input number in KW" value=""><br>

<label for="chiller-3">Chiller 3</label><br>
<input type="number" onkeyup=`addAll()` class="input-field" id="chiller-3" name="chiller-3" placeholder="Input number in KW" value=""><br>

<label for="chiller-4">Chiller 4</label><br>
<input type="number" onkeyup=`addAll()` class="input-field" id="chiller-4" name="chiller-4" placeholder="Input number in KW" value=""><br>

<label for="chiller-5">Chiller 5</label><br>
<input type="number" onkeyup=`addAll()` class="input-field" id="chiller-5" name="chiller-5" placeholder="Input number in KW" value=""><br>

<p id="output">Output goes here</p>
```

---

```
function addAll() {
const chiller1 = Math.floor(document.getElementById("chiller-1").value);
const chiller2 = Math.floor(document.getElementById("chiller-2").value);
const chiller3 = Math.floor(document.getElementById("chiller-3").value);
const chiller4 = Math.floor(document.getElementById("chiller-4").value);
const chiller5 = Math.floor(document.getElementById("chiller-5").value);
const allChillersValue = chiller1 + chiller2 + chiller3 + chiller4 + chiller5;
// console.log(allChillersValue);

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = allChillersValue;
};
```

Comment: What method are you using to test this in VS Code?

Comment: @daddygames - I am using the Live Server extension, which is loading the whole HTML page correctly, and is updating when I make visual changes, but doesn't seem to be doing much of anything with my JS file. I've included <script src="./script.js"></script> in the body tag and both files are saved in the same folder etc. I'm getting the same result even when I bring the JS code into the HTML file directly too. But still working fine in Codepen

Comment: It appears to be a It's a copy-paste issue. I've posted an answer that should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

the issue come from the way you add the keyup event listener

```
 onkeyup=`addAll()`
```

the valid html syntax is

```
onkeyup="addAll()"
```

but a better way i can advice is use addEventlistener method on all input-field class

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName('input-field')].forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('keyup', addAll);
});
```

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName('input-field')].forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('keyup', addAll);
});

function addAll() {
const chiller1 = Math.floor(document.getElementById("chiller-1").value);
const chiller2 = Math.floor(document.getElementById("chiller-2").value);
const chiller3 = Math.floor(document.getElementById("chiller-3").value);
const chiller4 = Math.floor(document.getElementById("chiller-4").value);
const chiller5 = Math.floor(document.getElementById("chiller-5").value);
const allChillersValue = chiller1 + chiller2 + chiller3 + chiller4 + chiller5;
console.log(allChillersValue);

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = allChillersValue;
}
```

```html
<h3>Chiller capacity</h3>
<p>Please input each chiller’s rated capacity in kW. The rated capacity is on the chiller nameplate.</p>

<label for="chiller-1">Chiller 1</label><br>
<input type="number" class="input-field" id="chiller-1" name="chiller-1" placeholder="Input number in KW" value="" required><br>

<label for="chiller-2">Chiller 2</label><br>
<input type="number" class="input-field" id="chiller-2" name="chiller-2"placeholder="Input number in KW" value=""><br>

<label for="chiller-3">Chiller 3</label><br>
<input type="number" class="input-field" id="chiller-3" name="chiller-3" placeholder="Input number in KW" value=""><br>

<label for="chiller-4">Chiller 4</label><br>
<input type="number"  class="input-field" id="chiller-4" name="chiller-4" placeholder="Input number in KW" value=""><br>

<label for="chiller-5">Chiller 5</label><br>
<input type="number" class="input-field" id="chiller-5" name="chiller-5" placeholder="Input number in KW" value=""><br>

<p id="output">Output goes here</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a copy-paste issue. VS Code has turned single quotes `'` into ticks `` ` ``.

Change the ticks surrounding the onkeyup property value for each element to a single or double quote instead.

**INCORRECT**

`` <input type="number" onkeyup=`addAll()` class="input-field" id="chiller-1" name="chiller-1" placeholder="Input number in KW" value="" required><br> ``

**FIXED**

`<input type="number" onkeyup="addAll()" class="input-field" id="chiller-1" name="chiller-1" placeholder="Input number in KW" value="" required><br>`

By fixing those characters, the code will run.